# wget using oauth2 for googlesheets

Tags: logging, oauth-2.0, wget, google-sheets-api

I am new programing in command line. I want download a sheet of GoogleSheets using   wget for run an automatic proccess every day. I am looking how to loging with **OAuth2**.

I try with the next command but doesnt work. The archivement *file* generate is a html file to loggin the gmail account and after loggin download the sheet of Google Sheets.

**wget -O file  "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/LONG_ID_STRING/export?gid=0&format=csv" --user=user@gmail.com --password=password**

I would like use a OAuth2 key. I did with R program using the library googlesheets:

"*library(googlesheets)*

*gs_ls()*

*be <- gs_title("FILE")*

*gs_ws_ls(be)*
"

Any idea to do with command line. Thanks in advance!!! :)

Answer (score 6):

If you already have an OAuth2 access token, you can pass it in the "Authorization" header:

`wget --header "Authorization: Bearer <your access token>" -O file "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/LONG_ID_STRING/export?gid=0&format=csv"`

Unfortunately, that's the simple part. ***Getting*** an OAuth2 access token on the command line is more challenging.

You should first create your own project in the API Console or Cloud Platform console, which will give you your own OAuth2 client id and client secret.

Next, from the Google OAuth2 Developer Playground at https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/, you could then get an access token (and more importantly, a refresh token) with offline access, for the scopes https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets (and probably https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive), using your Client Id and Client Secret under the "OAuth 2.0 configuration" (it's the Settings icon - the little gear in the top right), by checking "Use your own OAuth credentials".

After you've added your client id and client secret, you can work through the steps on the left to ultimately get an access token and the refresh token.

Once you get through all of that, and have that refresh token, your script could periodically get a new access token using the REST instructions at https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#offline.

Be sure to protect your refresh token, and best of luck - it's tricky stuff to get right, lots of moving parts! Hopefully someone will post easier steps, but at least this can get you going.

- Tim